# WP_Query for current query in search page showing only post from custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-post-type, elementor

I am building a search page on Elementor. I have different post types set up. I have "games", "news" and more. All of them have their own specific design on the front end (I have set it up using custom skins).

What I want to achieve is when people search for the example game "Spin" they would see:

**1st row** (Post widget Nr. 1) Game card that is for the game "Spin"

**2nd row** (Post Widget Nr. 2 ) News card/s that has an article mentioning the game "Spin".

I already have the search page and it finds all the articles/games because I have selected the current query and that works fine, BUT the problem is that it shows like this:

**1st row** Game card and News article in the design of the Game card showcasing the search term

**2nd row** Game card and News article in the design of News article showcasing the search term.

I have tried to set the source to Current Query and then add a Query ID that is linked to this PHP code:

```
function my_query_by_post_types( $query ) 
{ $query->set( 'post_type', [ 'games' ] ); 
} add_action( 'elementor/query/query_games', 'my_query_by_post_types' );
```

I have also now tried:

```
    function filter_search_results( $query ) {
    if ( is_search() && $query->is_main_query() ) {
        $search_term = get_search_query();
        $query->set( 's', $search_term );
        $query->set( 'post_type', array( 'games' ) );
    }
}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'filter_search_results' );
```

But it still only shows the Current Query in each row with the selected design of custom skins. How can I make each row only show the search term in the post types I have selected?